# How to run locally a Microsoft Web App Bot after download my Bot source code?

Tags: azure, botframework, bots

I want to code my Web App Bot locally and do tests using the emulator, but I'm not able to "build" or "generate a .bot file" or "run the code into the emulator".

I created a Web App Bot:

[image]

[image]

Then I want to download all the code and use it with Visual Studio Code, also I have installed Bot Framework Emulator v4:

[image]

Finally, if I see the files I don't know how to run the code, I tried to run the build.cmd file,

[image]

[image]

At the end when I tried to test my solution with the emulator I don't have nothing to open:

[image]

Comment: Create the .bot file from the emulator and test. Please find the link for sample .bot file [basic.bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot/basic-bot.bot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have a .bot file, click on 'create a new bot configuration' in the Welcome page in the Bot Framework Emulator or File -> New Bot Configuration. Fill in the required fields and click save and connect.

If your bot is running with Microsoft Account (MSA) credentials, enter these credentials too.
Choose 'Encrypt keys stored in Bot Configuration' if you would like your .bot file to be encrypted. This is recommended especially if you have keys and other sensitive information in your bot file. CAUTION: If you choose this option, Emulator will encrypt the .bot file and give you a key. You need to keep this key in a secure place (e.g. Azure Key Vault). See here to learn more about bot file encryption.

[image]